# How can I use chpasswd to set a password to nothing (for SSH purposes)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, shell, passwords

I can create a user and set its password in one line like so:

```
echo <sudopw> | sudo -S useradd Bob && echo Bob:P4ssw0rd
                            | sudo chpasswd --crypt-method=SHA512
```

But I want to use chpasswd in the same way to create Bob without a password so I can SSH into him without needing one (**This is for a test environment. Changing SSH config files is not my goal.**)

How can I do this using chpasswd or something similar in one line?

Comment: very bad idea. use keys instead (`ssh-keygen`, `ssh-copy-id`)

Comment: This is for a test environment. For my purposes, changing any ssh files would not achieve my goal.